# How can I upload images in react js inside node server with custom directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern, multer

I'm using multer to upload images in react app but the problem is I cannot set custom directory for the images. There's a fixed directory in which the images are being uploaded. So is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Have you tried `const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })`

Comment: It doesn't allow me to add new files to a different directories... nevertheless I'm changing the directory after uploading the images which is working fine